# OnTap flutter function

Tags: flutter, ontap

I'm new to flutter, I've understood the basics pretty fast but I have this simple and dumb problem that I can't get over with. In my app, I have tried to link other pages with the button on my nav menu, so let's say I created a nav menu, and I have a button called settings, and for my settings menu I want to create a separate `settings.dart` other than `main.dart` so I can start with a clean code page (works better for me I think), and I want to link the button from the `main.dart` with the page from `settings.dart`.

I know it's dumb and simple but I just can't get it done - thanks!

```
ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.person),
            title: Text('Cont'),
            onTap: () => null  ,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            title: Text('Favorite'),
            onTap: () => null,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.share),
            title: Text('Distribuie'),
            onTap: () => null,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.notifications),
            title: Text('Notificari'),
            onTap: () => null,
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text('Setari'),
            onTap: () => null,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.description),
            title: Text('Policies'),
            onTap: () => null,
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Exit'),
            leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            onTap: () => null,
          ),
```

I searched and I discovered that many other say that `onPressed()` is better for this, but I've tried to do this but I just can't get it to work.

After the `onPressed` I tried to link the name with `.dart` in the function but nothing happened.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwT7N.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK67P.png)

Comment: You want the settings button when clicked to go to settings page?

Comment: Yes, i want when i tap the settings button to go to the other page named settings.dart

Comment: That's the file's name. The page name could be different. What is the class name of the page?

Comment: Check out this; https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [Flutter navigation basics](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

Example:

```dart
  ListTile(
      leading: const Icon(Icons.settings),
      title: const Text('Setari'),
      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SettingsPage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```